# How can I create a clickable first option in Material UI Labs Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Below you can find an example from the MUI docs on Autocomplete where I've passed a link to google, prior to the options list. However, I can't click that option, the event target is just the MuiAutocomplete, rather than the `<a>` I'm passing.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const Link = ({ children }) => (
  <Paper>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
      Go to Google
    </a>
    {children}
  </Paper>
);

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
      )}
      PaperComponent={Link}
    />
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-egi6p

Interestingly, passing open to the autocomplete

```
    <Autocomplete
      open // add this prop
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
```

allows this to work as expected.

Currently, I'm using a onMouseDown to make this work but feel this is possibly a bad solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix this by adding:

```
      onMouseDown={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
```

to your link so that your `Link` component looks like:

```
const Link = ({ children, ...other }) => (
  <Paper {...other}>
    <a
      onMouseDown={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
      href="https://www.google.com/"
      rel="nofollow"
      target="_blank"
    >
      Go to Google
    </a>
    {children}
  </Paper>
);
```

[image: Edit Link in Autocomplete Paper]

A separate fix that I've included is passing through any additional props to the `Paper` component (via `...other`). The `Popper` component [passes props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui/src/Popper/Popper.js#L191) to the `Paper` component that control its positioning, so the positioning will be incorrect without this change.

The reason why `event.preventDefault()` is necessary, is because the focus is on the input prior to the click. One of the default effects of the mouse-down would be to change focus from the input to the link. The [onBlur of the input](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L764) would trigger a close of the listbox portion of the `Autocomplete` which means the link would no longer be present and it would not continue on to the `onClick` behavior of the link. Calling `event.preventDefault()` prevents the focus change from occurring.