# React Material UI open modal from within autocomplete lose focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, modal-dialog, material-ui

I'm using the material-ui lib and I need to have an autocomplete where each item inside that autocomplete is clickable and opens a modal.

The structure in general is:

```
const ModalBtn = () => {
    ...
    return (
        <>
            <button ... (on click set modal to open)
            <Modal ...
        </>

    );
}

const AutoCompleteWithBtns = () => {
    return (
        <Autocomplete
            renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                value.map((option, index) => <ModalBtn />)
            }
            ...
        />
    );

}
```

> Note that the ModalBtn is a component that cannot be divided into two components of Button and Modal.

The issue is that when you click on the button inside the modal - the focus is kept inside the autocomplete, and the modal will never gets the focus (if I have an input inside the modal - I can't write anything inside).

Tried all the standard autocomplete/modal focus-related props (`disableEnforceFocus`, `disableEnforceFocus`, etc...) but nothing works.

Here is a [working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-butterfly-umv2h). As you can see - if you click on the button that is not inside the autocomplete component - everything works (you can add text inside the input field). If you click on the button that is inside the autocomplete - the input field inside the modal is not editable (you lose focus).

Here is an example of the issue:
[image]

Comment: Can you please check the sandbox, it's not working

Comment: @Sabbin sorry about that, should work now.

Comment: Yes it works, just have one question, do you need 2 separate modals with the same functionality? The question is that will you have more than one opened at the time?

Comment: Multiple modals should be supported, but the important thing is that I need the modal to be opened from within the autocomplete (I assume that once this issue is resolved, the nested modals should be resolved as well).

Comment: @RyanCogswell it does :) thanks for this! I usually wait with the award of the bounty till last day to get more exposure on the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with having the `Modal` rendered from within the `Autocomplete` is that events propagate from the `Modal` to the `Autocomplete`. In particular, click and mouse-down events are both handled by `Autocomplete` in a manner that causes problems in your case. This is primarily logic intended to keep focus in the right place as you interact with different parts of the `Autocomplete`.

Below (from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.11/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L842) is the portion of the `Autocomplete` code that is getting in your way:

```
  // Prevent input blur when interacting with the combobox
  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    if (event.target.getAttribute('id') !== id) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  // Focus the input when interacting with the combobox
  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();

    if (
      selectOnFocus &&
      firstFocus.current &&
      inputRef.current.selectionEnd - inputRef.current.selectionStart === 0
    ) {
      inputRef.current.select();
    }

    firstFocus.current = false;
  };
```

The default browser behavior when a mouse down event occurs on a focusable element is for that element to receive focus, but the mouse-down handler for `Autocomplete` calls `event.preventDefault()` which prevents this default behavior and thus prevents a focus change from the mouse-down event (so focus stays on the `Modal` itself as indicated by its blue focus outline). You can however successfully move focus to the Modal's TextField using the tab key, since nothing is preventing that mechanism of focus change.

The `Autocomplete` click handler is keeping focus on the input of the `Autocomplete` even if you click some other part of the `Autocomplete`. When your `Modal` is open, the effect of this is that when you click in the `Modal`, focus is moved briefly to the `Autocomplete` input element, but the focus is immediately returned to the `Modal` due to its "enforce focus" functionality. If you add the `disableEnforceFocus` property to the `Modal`, [you'll see](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-in-autocomplete-1gq9d?file=/src/App.jshttps://codesandbox.io/s/modal-in-autocomplete-1gq9d?file=/src/App.js) that when you click in the `Modal` (e.g. on the TextField) the cursor remains in the input of the `Autocomplete`.

The fix is to make sure that these two events do **NOT** propagate beyond the `Modal`. By calling `event.stopPropagation()` for both the click and mouse-down events on the `Modal`, it prevents the `Autocomplete` functionality for these two events from being executed when these events occur within the `Modal`.

```
      <Modal
        onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}
        onMouseDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
        ...
```

[image: Edit Modal in Autocomplete]

Related answer: [How can I create a clickable first option in Material UI Labs Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291614/how-can-i-create-a-clickable-first-option-in-material-ui-labs-autocomplete/59293021#59293021)

Comment: A well compiled and explained answer (y)

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code was that the Modal was rendered from within the tag of the `AutoComplete` component, which was not ok because of the visibility of the components, the hierarchy of the components was the issue.

The fix is to move the `Modal` within the `FixedTags` component and pass the open handler to the `ModalBtn` in the `renderTags` prop;

I've updated your sandbox with a working variant [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-surf-5dlf3)

The changes are below

```js
const ModalBtn = ({ handleOpen }) => (
  <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
    Open Modal (not working)
  </button>
);

const FixedTags = function() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        options={autoCompleteItems}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        defaultValue={[autoCompleteItems[1], autoCompleteItems[2]]}
        renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option, index) => <ModalBtn handleOpen={handleOpen} />)
        }
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Fixed tag"
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="items..."
          />
        )}
      />
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <h2 style={{ color: "red" }}>This one doesn't work</h2>
          <p>Text field is not available</p>
          <TextField label="Filled" variant="filled" /> <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <FixedTags label="Standard" />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Moving the modal itself outside of the autocomplete tags is indeed a valid solution, however not a good one. The `ModalTbn` is a complete (a closed component, you can say) that renders a button and opens a modal upon click. Those two are coupled and I really prefer to not divide them.

Comment: In fact your code has a memory leak isue, because let's say you have 1000 tags in one autocomplete, you have 1000 modals in that autocomplete. Why render 1000 components when you can access only one at a time? Let's say it's nested of 6 leves 1000 each. You will have 6000 modal components and 6 rendered? You cannot open 2 modals from the same level at any time so why have them? That's the beauty of react, each element can be a component itself, keep the button in a component, keep the modal in another, keep the state and handlers in another... Composition

Comment: Needless to say, at 6000 tags, you have 12000 handlers and 6000 state objects laying around...

Comment: The modal will be rendered only when it's open (which is indeed the beauty of react), so this is not an issue. In any case you need to save the data of the content of the modal somewhere (even if you don't display it) so I'm not really worried about the "memory leak" (which I don't have in the example). You might consider this as a waste of memory, but not a leak (one the autocomplete element will be removed - the buttons and the modals will also be removed, and the memory will be freed).

Comment: The dialog component will be rendered on open indeed, but the state objects, now I saw there are 2, why is the style in the state when it's static idk, anyway, the state and handlers are created for each one. Personally I don't think is a better way of doing this like you did. I'll look for a solution if there is any in that case. There are 2 ways of typing in your example, either set `autoFocus` on the input but if you click outside it's gone. Either right-click on it and it will work... don't know why